# Build depended-on libraries automatically with Maven / NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, dependency-management

I use Maven with NetBeans to build my project. I have a few common libraries, and a lot of projects that depend on some of those libraries. Those projects list these libraries as regular `dependency` tags in their `pom`s.

When I build a library, it is installed into the local repository. When I build a project, it looks for the library there. However, it's easy to forget to build the library, and then its previous build will be used. So I'd like to build the libraries automatically whenever a project that depends on them is built.

I realize Maven has no idea that these dependencies are actually other projects. But NetBeans knows that. For example, when I 'update with dependencies', it *does* update all the depended-on projects from the SVN repo. I just want the same thing for the build action.

The Web is full of articles on multi-module protects, but that's not what I need. My libraries are independent projects, they shouldn't be modules of every project that depends on them (if that's at all possible).

Comment: Before reading your last paragraph, I would have said: Put your libraries and all the projects that depend on them into one large multi-module-project ... in eclipse, there is something called "Workspace resolution" which allows to directly reference projects as dependencies so that all changes are immediately propagated to the other projects (at least while working in eclipse). Maybe NetBeans has something similar?

Comment: @JFMeier Well, changes are propagated when I run or debug projects (files are compiled on save to temp dirs). But when I build them to release, the build is delegated to Maven, and it ignores those temp class files and looks for the jars in the repo, as it should.

Comment: Then I would write a small script that builds everything in your desired order (this would be automatic in multi-module). Your workflow seems to imply that you use SNAPSHOT versions for everything (otherwise you would need to adjust the dependency versions anyway). This is not the common practise for releases.

Comment: @JFMeier, OK, that makes sense for release builds. But NetBeans also delegates some other actions to Maven, such as "run all tests for the current project". They too use repo libs and therefore fail if a lib is outdated.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing here. But you say you would like to build your library if your project is being built? Why? The library is used by the project. So I would assume exactly the opposite. Means to build the project which is depending on the library...For me it sounds like you misunderstand the concept of libs...If those libs are independent projects than handle them that way. This means to make a release of those libraries. Than use the released version in your projects...If you have changes make a new release that's it... This can be simplified by using a CI solution like Jenkins...

Comment: @khmarbaise, say, I have a library with utility classes and a project that uses that library. I need to change a method in the library to implement new functionality in the project. I do that, I run it, it works (“compile on save” makes NetBeans use the most up-to-date code). Then I run all the tests on my project to make sure I haven't broken anything. And it all breaks because *now* NetBeans uses the old library in the local Maven repo. And I don't want to make a new release after every minor change.

Comment: First you library should have tests to make sure you haven't broken anything..and if so you have to change the major version your lib( semver.org)...furthermore If your rate of changing in the lib is so high it sounds like the library is not an independent project...so it should be part of the project...If your project is so highly coupled (cause everything is broken based on an older version) there seemed to be other problems..Furthermore you can use a SNAPSHOT of the lib and in Netbeans configure to use the most recent version...(`mvn -U ...` on command line)....

Comment: @khmarbaise, I wouldn't say it's highly coupled, it's just a bunch of utilities used by many projects. But during active development, yes, I may change it quite often (changes are backwards compatible and the library comes with the tests too). So yes, a SNAPSHOT is exactly what I need here, but the problem is to get NetBeans to compile those lib snapshots automatically whenever I compile the project. Sounds like a very typical task to me.

Comment: It is highly coupled based on your description and the changes what you described exactly shows that...Apart from that if changes are backwards compatible so there should no break of your project by using an older version...As I mentioned before the direction of dependency is from lib to project and not the other way around..This means you change the lib it will be built (best on command line mvn install) and your project should pickup the new version...Apart from that I don't use Netbeans in Eclipse it is not a problem based on the workspace resolution (or forcing it.)...

Comment: @khmarbaise, it *does* break because the lib misses the functionality I need for the new version of my project. And I don't get why it should be the other way around. Say, the new version of my project needs to understand the new version of some file format. The file reader is in the lib because it's used by many projects. I update the lib to support the new format, then I run the project's tests and they fail because the old lib doesn't support the new format.